# serving content on http / https

Tags: 6, ssl

I am confused about using and setting up ssl on website. 
On my site I would like to serve some pages using https protocol. From my understanding of what I read, I need to set up

1. ssl certificate - so site can be accessed from http and https
2. use module like [secure pages](https://drupal.org/project/securepages) to redirect users to https on certain pages.

Is this the correct way of what I want to achieve? Moreover, my concern is about duplicate content - what is the solution for restricting https to be crawled? I hope someone can put somelight on this. Thank you.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74748/using-ubercart-with-https-protocol/74792 - edit, not duplicate.